# Need help with a Fourier series question

Tags: fourier-series

I don't know if it's been asked before (if it has please give me the link), and I don't understand latex or anything so I'll write it in plain words:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x & \text{for } -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \\
π-x & \text{for } \frac{\pi}{2}< x \leq \frac{3π}{2}
\end{cases}
$$
Find the Fourier series.
I feel like the function is odd so it should be simple but I keep messing it up.

Comment: Please show what you have done.

Comment: Ok so I found a_0 = 0 using L = 2π and solving on the interval [-π/2,3π/2] but  my a_n ends up as a long line: (2/πn^2)(cosnπ/4) - (2/πn^2)(Cos3nπ/4) -(1/2n)(Sin nπ/4) - (1/2n)(Sin3nπ/4) and idk how to simplify that. Sorry if it's unreadable, I'd really appreciate it if someone did it all from the start.